# How to download files stored in the filesystem with django

Tags: python, django, django-views, file-transfer

I am developing an application where the user can upload some files to the server.
To upload the files I use this model and this view

```
model
class Documentacion(models.Model):
      id_doc = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      id_proceso = models.ForeignKey(Proceso,db_column='id',verbose_name='Proceso')
      tipo_docu = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False,verbose_name='Tipo Doc.')
      fecha = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
      autor = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=False)
      descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True,null=True)
      documento = models.FileField(upload_to='docs/')
```

View to upload files:

```
def DocuView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = DocuForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
       if form.is_valid():
          #docu = Documentacion(documento = request.FILES['documento'])
          #docu.save()
          form.save()
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/index/')
    else:
       form = DocuForm()
    return render_to_response("docu.html",
                              {'form':form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I render a table using django-tables2 to list all the files.
My question is how can I download the files listed in the table.
The column with the name of the document is a url link, but when I click the link I get the error:

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:

I don't know if I need to implement another view to handle the download or what I have to do.
the files uploaded to the server are have different extensions like word, excel,txt etc

any advice

thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

view to render the list of files:

```
def ListaDocView(request):
    tabla = DocuTable(Documentacion.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request,paginate={"per_page":50}).configure(tabla)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'table':tabla})
```

Comment: how do you render the file link? if you are developing with DEBUG = True, is Django correctly setup to serve media files?

Comment: That is mydoubt. I don't know If I miss some setting or I need to create a view to handle the download. And when I see the file link I suppose will work. but apparently i have to setup to serve media files but i dont know how

Comment: this would be how to setup serving media files during development  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development . (this goes into the project's urls.py.)

Comment: you have to show us `MEDIA` _ `url` and `root` ..?